# My Access point ip 192.168.1.xxx and My router getaway it's 192.168.0.1, if i give my AP 192.168.0.xx not Accept

Tags: networking

My Access point ip 192.168.1.xxx and My router getaway it's 192.168.0.1 if I give my AP 192.168.0.xx not Accept

Comment: the term is `gateway` ... like a garden gate

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to solve the problem - eg the model if the AP and exactly what you are trying to achieve.  You may be able to fix/mitigate the issue by changing the netmask on both devices to 255.255.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for replay....

Comment: Router 1 (Home router) have getaway # 192.168.0.1
Router 2 (Office Router) Have getaway 192.168.1.1
My Node (Acceess point)default ip # 192.168.1.252

when i give my Node ip Static or Auto with router2 working good
but wher tray to connect with Router1 not working (i give ip 192.168.0.200, i leave same ip default(192.168.1.252)
not working

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a diagram showing the different networks, the different devices, and their IPs? Given that a device which is connected to multiple networks will most likely have multiple IPs, one for each network it’s connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure basics is:

#### Often used values, as an example:

Node IP: e.g. **129.168.0.`n`**
Gateway IP: **129.168.0.1**
Netmask: **255.255.255.0**

A "node" can be a computer, a switch, a WIFI AP (pure Access Point), a 'router with Wifi and DHCP' or similar.

The gateway IP should normally be e.g. your home router, that has the WAN-area link (Ethernet, Fiber or whatever).
This IP is where all packets with "unknown" i.e. "not on this LAN" IP-number is sent, so these can be forwarded to the WAN area. For this to work, the router or switch has to have some kind of WAN or Internet connection.

`n` should differ for every node.
But note that *`n`=255* i.e. 192.168.0.255 (with the example above) is the "Broadcast address" (more below), i.e. used for sending data to ALL nodes on the local network.

Now, Netmask tells which binary digits that defines the LAN's "Network address".
Each number in the dotted iPv4 address occupies 8 binary digits, so a corresponding netmask number of 255 tells; all bits in this group, as 255 equals '11111111' in binary.
The Zero (0) in the example then obviously leaves those bits free for addressing nodes in the LAN (Local Area Network).
Depending on the software; The same Network address and Netmask can be defined as `192.168.0.0/24` as that tells that the 24 upper bits of the given IP defines the LAN.
*This of course also means that *192.168.0.`0`* (with "zero" for the zero-bits in the netmask) cannot be used for a node - due to the fact that it denotes the ID of the Local network.*

Also note that "Broadcast address" above is related to the Network address by the fact that it has *additional* binary `1`-bits for the `0`-bits in the Netmask  - in practice making it be the highest numbered, last, IP address in the Network (the LAN).

*So in the end; "192.168.1.xxx and My router getaway it's 192.168.0.1" would probably mean that those nodes are on different LAN:s and therefore needs a setup with at least a common gateway between them.

To have nodes communicate with an "easily setup" LAN, make all things have the same Network address.*

Comment: The IP of a host/device doesn't determine the structure of the physical/L2 network. Some devices can come with "factory" pre-assigned IP/netmask, and if that does not fit into your existing network, what you need is not a gateway, but to change its IP/netmask.

Comment: Or, you can just even assigned a secondary IP/netmask on the host that you wish to access the AP from.

Comment: Now, those comments imply more advanced networks, :-)  1. That is beyond my knowledge, 2. I tried to describe a very basic setup in simplest possible manner. Feel free to edit and correct if something is weird, but i strongly suggest to keep (2) in mind.

Comment: `imply more advanced networks` what i implied / suggested is, consumer grade routers, APs, etc. pretty much always have their own out-of-the-box IP/netmask. When in the case that you can't / don't want all your other hosts at home to follow the vendor-chosen IP subnet, the solution is to change that IP/netmask. No gateway / advanced networks is needed / relevant ;)

Comment: Well, I did apparently not understand that from your wording. `192.168.0.1` or `129.168.1.1` are the most common ones I've encountered. My answer though should direct towards the same, change / set IP inside your own LAN (or use DHCP).